# Is there a force flag in windows azure to change the role size?

Tags: azure

I tried to change the role size (upwards) in an Azure role and got the following error after uploading

"The role size specified for role 'Website' in the newly uploaded package differs from the role size for this role in the currently deployed service. Changing the size of the role will cause all local data on the role instance to be lost.  Please use the Force flag if you want to allow the loss of local data."

which leads to the question - is there a force flag? Where is it? How do I set it?

Comment: I'm starting a bounty on this question because I'm sure there must be more to it than what I've answered with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its just appeared!

An update to the Management Portal today (20 Oct 2011) has added an "Allow VM size or role count to be updated" tick box to the Upgrade Deployment dialog. So I guess that's the shiny new Force Flag!

Comment: Indeed so. And here's the link: you'll need to do it from Fiddler or Powershell or a teensy bit of custom code, I'm afraid: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460793.aspx

Comment: It's an upgrade and that still creates new ATs.  You pass the package and specify staging/production.  That's what I was referring to above when I said you need to view this as part of your patching/update process and consider VIP swap (staging in this case).

Comment: I feel a bit guilty about marking my own answer correct after the effort others have put in, but I think this (and Jeremy McGees comment) is *now* the correct answer

Answer (score 3):

The information I've heard on the Azure forums is that it is not possible to modify the role size without a full redeploy (and this has been my experience as well).

Over time Microsoft has allowed more things to be modified during an upgrade and Mark Russinovich may have suggested in a Mix or TechEd presentation that role size modification would be supported some point in the future.

The error message you are receiving may be an early artefact of the implementation of a size upgrade enhancement. The research I've done (and I have done a LOT of asking around) would indicate that the "Force Flag" mentioned is not actually implemented yet - although I'm more than happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: It's appeared now, see @Andiih's comment below.

Answer (score 3):

Right now, the vmsize is inside of the package (cspkg) which is sent to AppFabric.  It's a decision which is part of the build/packaging.  So, to change it, you need to change the VMSize, build the package and then [re]deploy.

If you have a running system, you can avoid down time by using VIP Swap.  It will basically stand up another AT[s] in the staging slot with your new VM size and then swap over to it.

So, there's more moving parts involved but you can still change it with virtually no impact.

Comment: are you suggesting that I can add a new staging deployment of a different size to the live deployment, and VIP swap to it? That would be awesome! The worst case scenario is to end up with an IP adddress change.

Comment: Yes - that's what we do.  Changing the role is effectively a patch and our patch process is to (1) create a build (2) create a package (cspkg) which BTW has the role size in it then (3) do a deployment to staging and (4) do a VIP swap.  Can't remember but either the IP change is abstracted behind a VIP or DNS is updated - your DNS has a cname alias to the azure name given to you.  Look into VIP swap ...

Comment: in order to point the root (not www.) we can't cname, hence the staticness of IP's is vital.

Comment: Of course, as you may now know, the "force" flag is now documented as part of the new feature that allows you to change the VM size of a deployed instance. You NO LONGER need to REDEPLOY to change the VM size. So @bryanmac's comment "So, to change it, you need to change the VMSize, build the package and then [re]deploy." was true when he wrote it, but is now no longer the case. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460793.aspx

Comment: As you may know, an upgrade puts up new instances - that's why it passes in the url to the package and offers staging or production. It is redeploying ATs. As I noted above, you need to view it as part of your patching process.  You have two choices, do as an upgrade (rolls through your ATs 20% at a time) or as a VIP swap (deploy in staging and switch instantly).